# Laravel 5.4 - Enviar e-mail com texto em anexo?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

O caso é simples: preciso gerar um texto no ***Laravel*** baseado em `Array` e em seguida anexar esse arquivo texto com Attachments através do `Mail::to()`!

Comment: qual é o array ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O passo a passo de criar um arquivo texto e enviar via e-mail no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) é:

#### Passo 1:

Primeira coisa é configurar o [FileSystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) da pasta `storage` com o comando:

> [`php artisan storage:link`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk)

isso criará uma pasta dentro da pasta `public`, que é uma forma de organizar suas pastas no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) e colocar os seus arquivos dentro da mesma, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é dentro dessa pasta que será salvos os arquivos criados `.txt` a partir de algum `array`do [php](/questions/tagged/php).

---

#### Passo 2:

Agora é criar um arquivo de texto (`.txt`) com alguns valores de um `array`, ***exemplo***:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

$t = "";
foreach ($array as $i)
{
    $t .= $i . PHP_EOL;
}
```

e logo após para salvar na pasta `storage` o arquivo de texto faça:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('public')->put('400.txt', $t);
```

observe que o `Facade Storage` tem um `disk` com o nome de `public` que é a configuração contida em `app\config\filesystems.php`

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

essa configuração é responsável em dizer o local de armazenamento que é o mesmo do `link` criado da pasta `storage`, e não tenha preocupação isso já vem configurado.

O método `put` por fim cria um arquivo de texto com os dados do `array` que estão contidos agora na variável `$t`.

#### Passo 3:

Digite na linha de comando:

> `php artisan make:mail MailTxt`

é criado um classe e configuração para o envio do e-mail, segue:

```
<?php namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MailTxt extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('email_txt')
                ->from('email@com.pt')
                ->attach(public_path('/storage/400.txt'));
    }
}
```

que dentro do método `build()` vamos configurar o seguintes metodos:

- `view`: ***nome da view que é o layout principal do seu e-mail***
- `from`: ***quem está enviando o e-mail seria o endereço do e-mail***
- `attach`: ***o arquivo texto que foi criado anteriormente que será anexado***

com esses ***3 passos*** é enviado um e-mail com o respectivo anexo texto.

***Código completo:***

```
$array = [
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
  11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
];

$t = "";
foreach ($array as $i)
{
    $t .= $i . PHP_EOL;
}

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('public')->put('400.txt', $t);

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::to("parapua@sapo.pt")->send(new \App\Mail\MailTxt());
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [File System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem)
- [Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail)