# Imagem não está renderizando no email

Tags: laravel, angular

Estou enviando email com laravel, o img src da imagem que eu envio por email é enviada pelo frontend:

Ao realizar upload de uma imagem é atribuido a variável imageSrc o src da imagem:

```
handleInputChange(e) {
  var file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
  var pattern = /image-*/;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

    _handleReaderLoaded(e) {
      let reader = e.target;
      this.imageSrc = reader.result;
    }
```

Então eu tenho uma view blade que eu mando email:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
   <img src="{{$foto}}" />
</body>
</html>
```

O problema é que tem imagem que renderiza e outras imagens não.

Eu chequei no site https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter colando o imagesrc que chega no email, renderiza nesse site, mas no outlook e no gmail não mostra a imagem no email.

Esse é o image src que tento mostrar no email:

https://pastebin.com/3srKwRyw

Comment: Você tem que usar assim: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#inline-attachments

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234416/laravel-5-4-enviar-email-com-txt-em-anexo

Comment: Voce precisa definir o caminho real da imagem no servidor para que apareça no corpo do email